# Show html select field selected as per database laravel

Tags: html, laravel

I have a table `users` with column `stime`

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9Wl8.png)

**what i want to achieve** - i want the specefic html option `<option>` selected `selected` when it matches from the database

**Like** - if `stime = 600.0` then this option `<option value="600.0">10 minute</option>`

will be selected `<option value="600.0" selected>10 minute</option>`

Laravel Blade Code

```
    <form method="post" action="{{route('setstime2')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
    <div class="boxl" style="margin-left: 10%;">
        <h3 class="h31">Set Idle Time</h3>
<select name="select" class="form-select" style="margin-top: 8%;" aria-label="Default select example">
  <option value="60.0">1 minute</option>
  <option value="120.0">2 minute</option>
  <option value="180.0">3 minute</option>
  <option value="240.0">4 minute</option>
  <option value="300.0">5 minute</option>
  <option value="360.0">6 minute</option>
  <option value="420.0">7 minute</option>
  <option value="480.0">8 minute</option>
  <option value="540.0">9 minute</option>
  <option value="600.0">10 minute</option>
  <option value="660.0">11 minute</option>
  <option value="720.0">12 minute</option>
  <option value="780.0">13 minute</option>
  <option value="840.0">14 minute</option>
  <option value="900.0">15 minute</option>
  <option value="960.0">16 minute</option>
  <option value="1020.0">17 minute</option>
  <option value="1080.0">18 minute</option>
  <option value="1140.0">19 minute</option>
  <option value="1200.0">20 minute</option>
  <option value="1200.0">21 minute</option>
  <option value="1320.0">22 minute</option>
  <option value="1380.0">23 minute</option>
  <option value="1440.0">24 minute</option>
  <option value="1500.0">25 minute</option>
  <option value="1560.0">26 minute</option>
  <option value="1620.0">27 minute</option>
  <option value="1680.0">28 minute</option>
  <option value="1740.0">29 minute</option>
  <option value="1800.0">30 minute</option>
</select>
<div style="margin: -10px;"></div>
        <button type="submit" class="" style="margin-top: 28px;">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator to achieve this

```xml
<option value="60.0" {{ $user->stime === 60.0 ? 'selected' : ''}}>1 minute</option>
<option value="120.0" {{ $user->stime === 120.0 ? 'selected' : ''}}>2 minutes</option>
...
<option value="1800.0" {{ $user->stime === 1800.0 ? 'selected' : '' }}>30 minutes</option>
```

If `$user` is your logged in user, you can use the `auth()` helper or the `Auth` facade instead.

```xml
<option value="60.0" {{ auth()->user()->stime === 60.0 ? 'selected' : ''}}>1 minute</option>
```

```xml
<option value="60.0" {{ Auth::user()->stime === 60.0 ? 'selected' : ''}}>1 minute</option>
```

---

A very compact way of doing this for all options I see in your example (1 to 30 minutes) is using `foreach()`, `range()` and `Str::plural`.

```xml
<select name="select" class="form-select" style="margin-top: 8%;" aria-label="Default select example">
  @foreach (range (1, 30) as $mtime)
    @php($stime = number_format($mtime * 60, 1, '.', ''))
    <option value="{{ $stime }}" {{ $user->stime === $stime ? 'selected' : '' }}>
      {{ $mtime }} {{ Str::plural('minute', $mtime) }}
    </option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

An `@if/@endif` directive can also be used.

```xml
<option value="{{ $stime }}" @if($user->stime === $stime) selected @endif>
    {{ $mtime }} {{ Str::plural('minute', $mtime) }}
</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this:

```
<option value="600.0" @if ($user->stime === 600.0) selected @endif >10 minute</option>
```

Comment: sorry because @IGP answered first. but appreciate your work man